# Previous day excluding only Saturdays with php Carbon

Tags: php-carbon

I'm trying to get the previous day excluding Saturdays using Carbon, but I can only find how to get previous date excluding weekends.

So with:

```
$todayDate = Carbon::now();
$dayBefore = $todayDate->subWeekDay();
```

if today is Monday in $daybefore I get Friday, but I need Sunday and if today is Sunday I need Friday...

I can't find a way to exclude only Saturdays from day before.

nesbot/carbon => 2.41.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the previous day excluding saturdays like this:

```
$dayBefore  = Carbon::yesterday();
if ($dayBefore->isSaturday()) {
    $dayBefore = $dayBefore->subDay();
}
```